# How to quickly choose numbers and weights in such a way as to obtain a specific weighted sum?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an unordered set of digits and a set of weights, I want to match the digits to the weights in such a way that the weighted sum is a given number. Now I do it so that I put these digits into some first arrangement and check the weighted sum, then I swap the first digit with the second, if the weighted sum is closer to the expected one, then I leave it, if I don't undo it. Then I check all the numbers one by one.

How do you find these numbers faster? There are many such comparisons, and sometimes the weighted sum of numbers resulting from a given arrangement of digits differs by 1 from the expected one and to correct it you have to change places by more than 2 digits, so my algorithm does not work, then I draw a new arrangement of digits and do everything again , the problem is that here a lot depends on the draw, if the new initial setting is favorable, the number will be found quickly, and if not, there may be a lot of such draws.

Can me use artificial intelligence or a neural network or something?

Comment: I'm not sure your current algorithm is correct (but I'm tired so it might well be). But have you tried whether a very simplistic brute-force approach works for you? Just test every possible combination.

Comment: If brute-force is too slow, I'm sure there is a mathematical/numerical solution to this kind of problem already. I would research that before deciding to try it with a neural network. Also, I'm not convinced a neural network would be correct or fast either

Comment: As [this QA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183164/from-weighted-average-to-single-values) points out, this is an underconstrained problem when you don't have your set of numbers already. So I guess that solving for all possible solutions and then finding the right one is not helpful to you

Comment: If you don't like brute force, you could try doing some optimization. However. I'm not sure it will buy you much. Brute force is, I believe O(N2). You could try sorting both sets (a sort is typically O(NlogN). The max value will result when you multiply the largest values by the largest weights, the min when you multiply the largest values by the smallest weights. Your solution is somewhere in between. Try a few optimization algorithms (for example, try splitting the weights set into two and running min by max on one set and max by max on the other

Comment: How many digits and how many weights? Are the weights integers or not?

Comment: The number of digits varies, the larger the better, but they are always single digits from 0 to 9. The weights are always positive integers of different sizes.

Comment: So there are at most 10 digits, and also 10 weights? Is there a bound on weights, like <= 1000?

Comment: The digits may repeat, but it is always one digit, not a multi-digit number. I want to arrange these single digits into a number that meets the condition (or conditions), I want to arrange the numbers from the unordered set in the correct order. There will be more than ten digits, if performance is not a limitation, then I would like to be able to use sets for (this is not a fixed threshold) several thousand digits (a separate weight for each digit). It would be good if I could simultaneously look for a solution for two sets of scales.

Answer (score 2):

An approach to solve this problem is to use a hybrid solution of gradient descent and a genetic algorithm.

Here I am starting with a ordered set of factors (`double[][]`) and filtering those so that I keep the best `weights.Length`. I then generate from those best solutions so far a set of mutations where I swap one element from each position with a randomly chosen position in the array. So if I start with a single `double[]` of length 24 then I end up with 24 `double[]` arrays of length 24 where each array differs by having two elements of each array swapped. This creates a larger number of guesses and I then loop doing this process until one solution is within a `delta` that is acceptably close to the answer.

```
var weights = new [] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 17, 17, 18, 19, 19 }.Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();
var factors = Enumerable.Range(1, weights.Length).Select(x => (double)x).ToArray();

var goal = 83.0833333333333;
var delta = 0.000001;

var rnd = new Random();

var pool = new [] { factors };

double[] swap(double[] array, int n, int m)
{
    var output = array.ToArray();
    var t = output[n];
    output[n] = output[m];
    output[m] = t;
    return output;
}

double score(double[] sample) => sample.Zip(weights, (x, w) => x * w).Sum() / weights.Length;

double[][] generate(double[][] current)
{
    var best = current.OrderBy(xs => Math.Abs(score(xs) - goal)).Take(weights.Length).ToArray();
    var guesses =
        best
            .SelectMany(xs => Enumerable.Range(0, weights.Length), (xs, n) => swap(xs, n, rnd.Next(weights.Length)))
            .ToArray();
    return guesses;
}

while (!pool.Where(xs => Math.Abs(score(xs) - goal) < delta).Any())
{
    pool = generate(pool);
}

var result = pool.Where(xs => Math.Abs(score(xs) - goal) < delta).First();
```

The figure I've used for `goal` is the minimum possible weighted average. In this example the code effectively has to reverse the order of the original `factors` array. It does that in 0.019 seconds on my pc.

Comment: If you have the time or happen to know already, I'm curious  how it compares to xbrute force

Comment: Also... this is not guaranteed to terminate (though unlikely) or to give the best possible solution, right?

Comment: @lucidbrot - This is vastly faster than brute force. The number of permutations of 24 numbers is vast. Brute force may not even get a solution because of the use of `double` to store the numbers. This will always find a solution given a large enough `delta`.

Comment: I may well be wrong, but technically it could happen that you keep swapping the same numbers, right? My comment about termination was just that you ignore the case where the RNG keeps giving a really unhelpful random number.

Comment: @lucidbrot - That would be astronomically unlikely. In each iteration, with a list size of 24, I'm generating 576 random numbers. The chance of all of them being "bad" is exceedingly small.

Answer (score -1):

I know you tagged your answer C#, but I did not feel like opening visual studio and python should help you grasp it just as well.

I have simply done what I suggested in my comments: Run a brute-force algorithm:

```
import itertools
def solve(given_weights, numbers, given_sum):
    all_combinations = [zip(x,given_weights) for x in itertools.permutations(numbers, len(given_weights))]
    for combination in all_combinations:
        tuplified = [tuple(x) for x in combination]
        if weighted_sum(tuplified) == given_sum:
            return tuplified
    return None

def weighted_sum(combination):
    return sum([x[0] * x[1] for x in combination])
```

And when I run it with six weights, it is quick enough for me not having to wait:

```
python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> given_weights = [1,2,3]
>>> numbers = [4,5,6]
>>> from tmp import *
>>> weighted_sum(zip(given_weights, numbers))
32
>>> solve(given_weights, numbers, 32)
[(4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3)]

>>> weighted_sum(zip([1,2,3,6,5,4],[10,11,12,12,14,15]))
270
>>> solve([1,2,4,5,6,3], [15,14,12,12,11,10], 270)
[(12, 1), (12, 2), (11, 4), (14, 5), (15, 6), (10, 3)]
```

So I say just stick with the simple approach of brute-forcing it.
When I run it with nine numbers and nine weights, it takes about 2seconds though. So this approach really depends on the number of numbers you have.

Comment: "I did not feel like opening visual studio" - Please try to get the motivation.

Comment: Thanks but I need something more efficient than brute force.

Comment: @Enigmativity Unlikely. It wouldn't change my answer - it's an algorithmic question after all. I do find your answer better, but for its algorithmic value.